# parse error appears on fetching the json array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I know it's dummy question but I spent hours in this and cant find the cause. I have JSON array file and trying to fetch the array in jQuery but parse error appears. Here is my code:

```
var obj=[
    {
        id : 1,
        name : 'name1',
        age : 67,
        feedback : 'feedback1'
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        name : "name2',
        age : 30,
        feedback : 'feedback2'
    },
    {
        id : 3,
        name : 'name3',
        age : 59,
        feedback : 'feedback3'
    },
     {
        id : 4,
        name : 'name4',
        age : 17,
       feedback : 'feedback4'
    },

]
```

in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'data.json',
        error : function(that,e) {
            console.log(e);
        },
        success : function(data) {
            alert(JSON.parse(data.obj[0].name));

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to parse? A name? Check out id 2 by the way, `"name2'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **data.json** should be valid json.

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name1",
    "age": 67,
    "feedback": "feedback1"
 }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "name2",
    "age": 30,
    "feedback": "feedback2"
 }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "name3",
    "age": 59,
    "feedback": "feedback3"
 }, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "name4",
    "age": 17,
    "feedback": "feedback4"
 }]
```

You can check the validity of you json file here - http://jsonlint.com/